# Cannot install NodeJS via NUGET

Tags: .net, node.js, nuget

While trying to install Node.js via the Nuget package manager, I am getting the following error. No further information to tap into. Any idea what is happening there?

I tried changing the .NET framework version of the project but I still get the same issue.

A few other people on different forums have pointed out similar issues while installing nodejs via the package manager. Just want to make sure if this is known issue.

> Could not install package `nodejs-v.0.8.16 0.8.16`. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   `.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2`, but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.
>
> For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your problem statement; I believe you're trying to run Node.js from a localized directory within your solution directory structure instead of installing node.js separately.

The official package from the **Node.js Foundation** - *node.js* (note the ".") - [The Official node.js package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Node.js/) is what you are likely after, you'll notice this indeed does work when executed against a 4.5.2+ project like the one you were testing against:

```
Install-Package Node.js
```

Note: The absolute oldest version you can install for this particular package against a 4.5.2 project is 0.10.26.1 from what I tested.

---

Side note:

What you were referencing is a substantially older package of *"nodejs"*  (note the missing ".") from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nodejs-v.0.8.16/) which I checked out myself, it doesn't install irrespective of the framework version specified in project properties, also 0.8.16 is old.

Comment: Right. I was actually trying to install Gulp.js and it was downloading that as a dependency. Then I tried to install nodejs first and typed in nodejs directly into the Browse. That came up with the package nodejs-v0.8.16. The published date is 2012, no wonder it causes issues. Just wondering why they are keeping it as a separate package in there.

Comment: Not sure about the reasoning either but you can try contacting the owners of the package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nodejs-v.0.8.16/ContactOwners) if you're desperate to know.